# What does inspect.exe do to make controls visible?

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I'm trying to get specific control via UIAutomationCore.dll library. 
The problem is, I cannot see it from code *(desired children are not found)* and UISpy *(it shows an exception "UI Automation tree navigation is broken. The parent of one of the descendants exist but the descendant is not the child of the parent")* until I start inspect.exe even for a second -- then it appears and this effect stays until program window is reopened.

There is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42383170/unable-to-get-deepest-iuiautomationelement-without-one-of-inspect-exe-magnify-e), but apps are running on the same non-admin level of UAC.

Here is my code. This is an example for VS Code tabs, but I also faced this trouble with Slack and its "document".

```
static bool Do(IntPtr handle)
{      
    CUIAutomation8 uiAutomation = new CUIAutomation8();
    int propertyName = 30005;
    int propertyLocalizedType = 30004;

    IUIAutomationElement element = uiAutomation.ElementFromHandle(handle);

    if (element == null)    
        return false;    

    IUIAutomationCacheRequest cacheRequest = uiAutomation.CreateCacheRequest();
    cacheRequest.AddProperty(propertyName);

    IUIAutomationCondition tabCondition = uiAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(propertyLocalizedType, "tab");

    IUIAutomationElementArray elements = element.FindAllBuildCache(
                    TreeScope.TreeScope_Descendants,
                    tabCondition,
                    cacheRequest);

    if (elements == null || elements.Length == 0) 
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; ++i)
    {
        //do something
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The question is the wrong way around, should be "what do controls do to make themselves visible to inspect.exe".  Which is the ultimate curse of UI automation, when you have a balky app then you can't do anything but file a bug report with the app owner.

Comment: Are you using your cursor to find the control? Generally I have found that inspect doesn't do anything special to make control visible. Most of the time when I was using inspect I would hover over a control and that would cause the visual tree to be updated and it would show up in inspect. In one application for instance hovering over a control caused a its tool tip to be generated which caused its automation peer to be generated.

Comment: @MaxYoung, no, I can see it in inspect's visual tree without any hover or interaction. And when I interact with program when my code runs in loop, nothing changes -- still no "tab" elements.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar experience - some of the application's UI tree was invisible until inspect.exe ran briefly.   I eventually discovered that setting the registry entry HKCU\Control Panel\Accessibility\Blind Access\On to "1" made it behave correctly.   The really interesting parts of this are:

- The application itself does not read this registry value.
- The behavior doesn't change after setting this registry value until you log out and log back in - no matter how many times you start or stop the application(s).
- After about 20 times of running the application, my piece of code trying to read it, and Inspect.exe, everything started working even without Inspect.exe running.   Apparently, something somewhere is setting this registry entry on its own after a while.  (Which is how I found it)
- While the missing-subtree was very reproducible on Windows 7 and 8.1, it was less reproducible on Windows 10 - only occurring on one of the 4-5 machines we tried it on.
- I can't find any documentation on what this Registry value actually *means* however.  It doesn't seem to directly map to any Ease of Use settings.  However, I didn't look extensively.